# list action servers

Tags: ros, action-server

[image: Rosanswers logo]

How can I get a list of the names of action servers?

Is there also a way to get a list of the actions that a given action server has?

Using either a cmd line or python would be preferable for me.
Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/222748/list-action-servers/) by [Fry](https://answers.ros.org/users/25033/fry/) on ROS Answers with karma: 126 on 2015-12-17

Post score: 8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Each action server publishes 5 topics (my server is named `test` below):

```
/test/cancel
/test/feedback
/test/goal
/test/result
/test/status
```

So you can e.g. use `grep` to the output of `rostopic list` to get the list of available actions, e.g.

```
rostopic list | grep -o -P '^.*(?=/feedback)'
```

---

Originally posted by [peci1](https://answers.ros.org/users/7736/peci1/) with karma: 1366 on 2015-12-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 14

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on 2016-02-01**:
While this works very well for me, I also opened a ticket for a new feature https://github.com/ros/actionlib/issues/44